# Can I use NVIDIA nsight to troubleshoot WPF performance?

Tags: c#, wpf, nvidia, nsight

I have a WPF application with a bottleneck on the GPU. I thought I could use NVIDIA nsight to see what WPF is doing, but the setup documentation says I should disable WPF hardware acceleration. Without disabling hardware acceleration I still get results, but now I'm not sure - are these results incorrect? Is there no way to use nsight on WPF applications?

Comment: I don't the answer but wanted to point out that Microsoft has published a suite of dedicated [WPF performance tuning tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Microsoft's performance suite is not detailed enough to help me. If I'm fill rate limited I need to know exactly what I'm copying. nsight seems to have the information, like PIX does but looks better. My only concern is that the data I see is wrong somehow and I end up wasting my time chasing ghosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a new version just came out and it supports WPF. Just needed to wait.

Comment: can you publish how you acheived that? trying to launch graphics debugging on a WPF app yields error messages from the NSight output window saying "Unable to launch ... because architecture type is MSIL (System.InvalidOperationException)"

Comment: Can't remember what I did, but I do remember it was a dead end

Answer (score 1):

Your WPF app is a managed binary, and Nsight don't support launch managed files for Graphics debug.

Thanks
An